# Using the extra SATA ports on a 2006 Mac Pro under Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, hardware, mac-pro

i have a 2006 MacPro (Dual, Dual Core Xeon) which is currently running Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V. I have read (and checked in my case) that there are 2 extra SATA ports on the mother board of the MacPro (Found them too...). Anyway, i also read that the SATA ports are turned off in BootCamp, for reasons Apple only know (*cough* we all know why *cough*). Anyway, the post i read this on was quite old, and given my Mac Pro is not actually using BootCamp (just booted from the win2k8r2 disk, and there is no Mac Partition at all on this machine) does anyone know off hand if this should work? I am hoping to take apart the machine over the weekend to see if this will actually work, but before i do, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use those ports once you installed the AHCI drivers. However, you'd still need to boot Windows from a disc connected to one of the drive sleds.

They got rid of this mess with the 2009 and later machines, btw.

Comment: Cool. sounds like it could be what i need. Now all i need to do is try it. I will be booting off one of the drives in the Sled, so thats not a problem... Where do i get these AHCI drivers though?